# NoMethodError at before_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error message when submitting a form that creates an object and nested objects:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `ratio' for nil:NilClass):

app/models/sale.rb:57:in `set_total_valuation'
app/controllers/api/v1/sales_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

Here's my model

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :distribution_entries, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :distribution_entries, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  before_save :set_total_valuation

  private

  def set_total_valuation
    main_ratio = self.distribution_entries.find { |object| object["item"] == "Main" }.ratio / 100
    self.total_valuation = self.target / main_ratio
  end
end
```

I think I'm getting nil because distribution_entries doesn't exist at this stage of the creation cycle but when seeding it works fine.

Comment: During the creation method, or either your sale instance does not have any distribution_entries or none of them satisfy the block (object['item'] == "Main").
Please update the post with your view/controller.
You can also place a breakpoint (byebug or binding.pry) before the failing line to check what's in distribution_entries.

Comment: The sale form must always have this specific entry in distribution_entries and I have checked I'm sending them correctly.
I have placed a puts at the first line in set_total_valuation and get this:
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> so it's empty at that moment
It's an API so no view associated and controller is quite classic.

Comment: `def create
    @sale = Sale.new(sale_params)
    @sale.user = current_user

    if @sale.save
      render :show, status: :created
    else
      render json: @sale.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end`

Comment: My question is why aren't my nested objects created when submitting the form thus resulting in this NoMethodError ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case if it’s plausible and likely there will be scenarios where there won’t be distribution entries yet on a sale then you can add a conditional to your call back and check `distribution_entries.present?` with another method or a proc (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#using-if-and-unless-with-a-proc):

`before_save :set_total_valuation if: Proc.new { |sale| sale.distribution_entries.present? }`